# Will Google API trigger multiple times when updating current location?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-api, expo, react-native-maps

**UPDATED**

Found out more information about this question on the github page from the library I use.

***Answer:***

When using the library [react-native-maps-directions](https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions) the google API only gets triggered when the origin, destination or waypoint updates. Since then there is a new calculation needed.

***Question:***

So I have this question because I currently am using the Google Directions API which uses the "pay-as-you-go model". Now I am scared to use the API in my code that when the user location updates it will triggers the API again so it will think I want a new result from the Directions API.

I'm using the [react-native-maps-directions](https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions) library to show the route on the map.

There is just more clarification needed for me.

> Does the API only get called once when opening the component or will
>   it also trigger during the update of the user location even I don't
>   want to do something with the user location in the query?

Here is a part of my code that shows the current flow I'm talking about:

**The API Key gets registered in the constructor**

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 if (props.apiKey !== undefined) {
   this.apiKey = props.apiKey;
 }

 this.origin = { latitude: this.route.waypoints[0].latitude, longitude: 
 this.route.waypoints[0].longitude };
 this.destination = { latitude: this.route.waypoints[this.route.waypoints.length - 1].latitude, longitude: this.route.waypoints[this.route.waypoints.length - 1].longitude };
 this.GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = this.apiKey;
}
```

**The getUserLocation get called in componentWillUnmount** *(It is the only thing that has to update and I don't want to make this to trigger the API)*

```
getUserLocation = async () => {
 this.location = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
  {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    distanceInterval: 1,
    timeInterval: 100,
  },
  (newLocation) => {
    let coords = newLocation.coords;

    console.log("USER LOCATION", coords);
    this.setState({
      userLocation: coords,
      region: {
        LATITUDE: coords.latitude,
        LONGITUDE: coords.longitude
      }
    });
  },
  (error) => console.log(error)
);
};
```

**I use the API Key in the render, not where the marker of the user get updated**

```
<MapViewDirections
  origin={this.origin}
  waypoints={this.coordinates.slice(1, -1)}
  destination={this.destination}
  apikey={this.GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
  strokeWidth={20}
  strokeColor="#DD8526"
/>
```

**This is the marker that gets updated, it's in the same MapView as the block above**

```
<Marker style={styles.markerStyle} coordinate={{ latitude: lat, longitude: lng }} title="Your Location">
  <Text style={styles.markerTextStyle}>You</Text>
  <Image source={require("./../../assets/img/other/you.png")} style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }/>
</Marker>
```

There is only one Component in the render that updates so I don't know if this will actually trigger the API call again.

**Feel free to say it when you need anything to be more specified to bring the right information about this!**

Comment: Do you intend to get new directions or route from the user location to the specified destination whenever the user location gets updated?

Comment: No, this is not what I want to do. I'm assuming this won't affect the Google API? I just found out that the library clearly says it only do a fetch request when the origin or destination changes. Found this later after posting this question. I'll update my question with the answer provided if needed by someone with the same question

Comment: Great find! I suggest taking a look as well on the official Google Maps Platform APIs billing documentation for more information on how Directions API is being billed: https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#directions